# No start after error code P0118

Tags: nissan, cranks-wont-run, altima

I replaced my the Coolant Temperature Sensor and after replacing with an OEM Nissan part it has not started. I have a Nissan Altima SL 2002 2.5L 4 Cylinder.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you had the codes read after the CTS was replaced? What if any are there?

Comment: Paulster2, thanks for replying. I indeed placed the scanner after the new original part was replaced and erased the P0118 code before trying to crank it. Once I disconnected and reconnected the scanner after erasing the code, the scanner was free of error codes. Unhooked the scanner and cranked. No start at all. I even replaced the battery since after 7 cranks it went dead. The car has not started at all. I have been without a car for a week....